# Antithesis for an elf ranger?

Tags: dnd-4e

In the campaign I'm currently playing in, the DM is having us make anti-characters for us to fight. I'm a walking stereotype (ELf Ranger) and so the DM said my anti has to be a dwarf. What class should he be? and should he be a dwarf or a duregar?

Comment: I would rephrase this somewhat: you're not just looking for any dwarf idea, but specifically the antithesis of the Elf Ranger.

Comment: This is still incredibly broad. We don't even know if your Elf Ranger is melee or ranged, but more than that we need to know your setting, your characters abilities, any other backstory that's been developed already, and you're going to use this antithesis for etc. etc etc.

Comment: I think this is going to be "primarily opinion-based" no matter how it's written.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to find the opposite of your current character, you should take each aspect of your character and turn it on its head. Here are a few things you could consider(but there are many more):

#### Physical

- Gender
- Height
- Weight
- Hair colour/ bald
- Facial hair
- Scarring
- Tattoos
- Piercings

#### Personality

- Brave/ Cowardly
- Smart/ Dumb
- Charismatic/ Despicable
- Good/ Evil

#### Location

Are you from a city and wear metal armour and polished shoes? Your anti-character should wear leathers and pelts.

Are you from the Feywild, maybe your opposite comes from the Shadowfell.

#### Role In Combat

- Ranged/ Melee
- Arcane/ Divine/ Martial/ Psionic/ Primal
- Striker/ Leader/ Controller/ Defender

#### Other

This is a great opportunity for you to really think about what your character is all about. Maybe not everything about your anti-character is a bad quality. Maybe the presence of some quality of his highlights your own lack of it (such as maybe he would risk his like for his companions if you are more selfish).

Comment: Good answer to a too-vague question.  Teaches him to fish.

Answer (score 3):

According to Tolkien (arguably one of the most significant influences on D&D and fantasy RPGs in general), elves are the opposite of orcs - the latter were created from corrupted elven stock, IIRC. The antagonism between elves and dwarves is another genre staple, but has always seemed to be characterized more as a love-hate relationship, since the two races differ in personalities, cultures etc., but are ultimately both 'good guys'.

Depending on what setting you're playing in, an orc or half-orc character might be more suited as the antithesis to your Elf Ranger.

Zibbobz' suggestion about the Necromancer sounds excellent. Assuming your Ranger is, as you say, a walking stereotype (i.e. tree-hugging animal-lover with dual-wielded weapons and all that jazz), then a good anti-character to act as a foil to your Elf could be a (Half-)Orc Necromancer; a bookish recluse who has no reverence or respect for nature - or indeed, any living creatures - and would much rather hang out at a nice graveyard, thank you very much.

(Corollary: if you're high level enough that you'd have to shop for magic items for your anti-character, you may want to look into something similar to the Hand of the Mage, from previous editions of D&D. Even though it's only power is to cast the 0th-level spell Mage Hand at will, it's described as a 'mummified elf hand' - definitely the kind of bling that an anti-Elf Necromancer would cherish.)

Answer (score 1):

Anti-Elven Ranger?

Barbarian Dwarf.

Or if you're feeling particularly daring, Necromancer Dwarf.

OR if you have source for it, a Drow would be an even more stark contrast.

Ooooor you could do what I did when my Barbarian Elf ran into a Mirror of Opposition, and have it be a completely non-standard Elf.  A beer-chugging, loudmouthed, crass as all hell Barbarian with no regard for the sanctity of nature.

Ooooooor you could be even MORE daring and make it another Elven Ranger, but rather than a good-aligned one, make him stand for everything your character doesn't, using the same tools and tricks you use, but for the opposite ends.

In the end though, what truly opposes your character strongly depends upon *your character*.   All of these suggestions are starting points.  The end point should be a greater reflection on the character as you've played them, rather than the character steriotype.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a Duergar would be a nice variant for this request, but you should check with your DM if he will allow the race in play.

As for the class, you have a couple of choices:

- stereotype: a Dwarf Fighter or Cleric would be the stereotypical choices. Other favored dwarf classes, according to [D&D4 Wiki](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Dwarf) are the Paladin, Barbarian, Runepriest or Warden. A lawful-good fighter or cleric, especially worshipers of Erathis would be the good antithesis to a ranger, playing on the City/Society angle against the Nature/Wild spirit of Rangers.
- left-field choice: you could play a Dwarf Ranger, giving it an interesting backstory.

Comment: I was thinking Dwarf Ranger myself. Make it a melee, twin-striking beast. If the two characters ever got into a match against either, one of them is probably going to die on the first assault.